# Difference transformation and Stationarization of Moving Average

Tags: filters, noise, autocorrelation, time-series, moving-average

I have a temperature sensor data, I want to denoise it. The first thing that came to my mind was to take the moving average, it was very smooth but it is still not stationary. If I take the log difference, it becomes stationary according to ADF and KPSS, but is this the right thing to do? Is it the right thing to do difference transformation of the moving average? I am very confused about this. Can you evaluate it in terms of DSP/time series context? Also, my second question is whether the ACF/PACF graphs of a moving average filtered data make any sense? Let me ask the same thing for the log difference of ma.

Comment: The moving average is a form of low-pass filtering (LPF) with DC gain of 1 (or 0 dB).  You might want to consider other low-pass filters, like a simple first-order IIR.  Sometimes these other LPFs are called *"weighted average"*.